# What coast or river-adjacent city is in this photo?

Tags: usa, online-resources, where-on-earth, identify-this, photography

Can anyone identify the city in this picture?

[image]

It appears to be along a coast or a body of water.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47367/discussion-on-question-by-spike-fitsch-can-anyone-identify-the-city-in-this-phot).

Comment: From where did you obtain this photo? It isn't yours, or you'd know what it was showing. Please be sure to provide proper attribution when you reproduce somebody else's work.

Comment: @MarkMayo: ^ This reposted comment is not a "discussion" or "conversation"; it is a fundamental, legal critique of the question and must be addressed here. Please don't hide it again.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can think of a lot of reasons why this might not be necessary. For instance, I have a couple of hundreds of old photos that I took, but can't remember the place I took them. Then, it could be also a friends picture, etc.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Agreed. But "Own work" or "Friend's photo, posted with permission" are perfectly good attributions.

Comment: @DavidRicherby True

Answer (score 45):

This is New York City - looking east across the Hudson from New Jersey.
A similar viewpoint is available from [google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.7707909,-74.015868,3a,75y,158.39h,76.01t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-75vFHL7RYQE%2FVfXJrNJ3UxI%2FAAAAAAAAAMc%2FUPWAC1QV7ho-z7GU0DIB1TNk7tR6RsQsQ!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh4.googleusercontent.com%2F-75vFHL7RYQE%2FVfXJrNJ3UxI%2FAAAAAAAAAMc%2FUPWAC1QV7ho-z7GU0DIB1TNk7tR6RsQsQ%2Fw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya340.33728-ro-0-fo100%2F!7i8704!8i4352!6m1!1e1)
[image]
Probably from around Port Imperial Blvd just north of the Lincoln Tunnel.
Your photo seems to be from a position a little further south than this one though - a bit closer to the tunnel - judging by the angles of the piers.

Comment: What is that wedge-shaped building in the middle left?

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson - that's [Via 57 West](http://www.via57west.com/)

Answer (score 37):

The city is New York, facing the Borough of Manhattan and the photo was taken at Kennedy Blvd and approximately  53rd Street in [West New York, New Jersey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_New_York,_New_Jersey).  I lived there for nearly a decade and would spot it in a moment.  Screen cap from Google street view...

[image]

Source: [Google Maps](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/West+New+York,+NJ+07093,+USA/@40.7794284,-74.0125403,303m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c258131938b8d5:0xe39c30a8afef2d96!8m2!3d40.7878788!4d-74.0143064)

See also: [A view of New York (Manhattan) from West New York, New Jersey at dawn](https://www.flickr.com/photos/drunkcat/3049580133)

Comment: I think my google-fu beats yours ... ;)

Comment: @brhans, ok, I'll up vote your answer :)

Comment: Is Manhattan a city?

Comment: @vclaw see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borough_(New_York_City). NYC is so dense they split it into five smaller cities.

Answer (score 18):

That is the City of New York and the island/borough of Manhattan.  It's a picture of the West Side, Hell's Kitchen, taken from Union City, New Jersey.

The pier on the right is the Intrepid.  The other piers are the cruise terminal.

And the pier all the way to the left is for garbage transfer.

Comment: OMG!  I didn't notice that, but really, who doesn't know what the West Side is :)